# How to set up SSH keyphrase caching with GnuPG Agent in NixOS?

Tags: ssh, gnupg, nixos

I'm using NixOS (unstable channel, at the moment) remotely, via SSH, so no graphical environment. I often push and pull Git repositories, and re-typing the passphrase for SSH keys gets old quick, so I'm trying to set up an agent to cache the passphrase.

With the latest releases, using GnuPG Agent with SSH support seems to be the recommended choice. I enabled the agent by uncommenting the following lines in configuration.nix:

```
  programs.gnupg.agent = {
    enable = true;
    enableSSHSupport = true;
    pinentryFlavor = "gnome3";
  };
```

Does the choice of `pinentryFlavor` matter here? I'm imagining that SSH asks the keys by its own prompt, and caches them using the agent, but a confirmation would be nice. As I said, I'm not using graphical interface.

The main question: it doesn't seem work by just by enabling agent from the configuration.nix. Something else clearly needs to be done, but I'm unable to find any documentation about how to properly enable the agent in NixOS.

Comment: One of the few notes I was able to find about this, was this: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/2a99df87f280df835e9b7e190d8f46ec but it complains that there is no service called gpg-agent. I was sure to nixos-rebuild switch after the configuration change, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: my NixOS ssh-agent wasn't working, as I'd unintentionally left [this workaround for ssh-agent on Ubuntu systems](http://askubuntu.com/a/634573/340840) in my dotfiles, inside `.bashrc`. Disabling that let the nix ssh-agent start working in new terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `configuration.nix` sets up configuration at `/etc/bashrc` to call `gpg-connect-agent` when bash is started and `/etc/set-environment` to set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. It also adds systemwide per-user systemd units at `/etc/systemd/user/gpg-agent*` that run per-user GnuPG key agents.

Finally, you must be sure to add the key to the agent using the `ssh-add` command; it isn't added automatically when SSH prompts the key passphrase.

This should be enough to make GnuPG agent work with SSH. <s>The choice of `pinentryFlavor` shouldn't also have effect when used over terminal.</s> Turns out you *should* set `pinentryFlavor` to curses when using over terminal. If you don't do that, the agent throws an error when re-authenticating.

(I'm not sure why I encountered various error conditions when I first enabled GnupPG. It works now with the default settings. It's possible that the systemd service wasn't properly started.)